# Specifying Elements In A Numpy Array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, spyder

I would like to create the numpy array which takes on the values in the range [0,10], with divisions between each element 0.1. How might I go about doing this? Hopefully my request is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @agconti answer, you can use what is called a **linspace**:

**Code:**

```
import numpy

a = numpy.linspace(0, 10, num = 101)  # num -> number of elements
print a
```

**Output:**

```
[  0.    0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9   1.    1.1
1.2   1.3   1.4   1.5   1.6   1.7   1.8   1.9   2.    2.1   2.2   2.3
2.4   2.5   2.6   2.7   2.8   2.9   3.    3.1   3.2   3.3   3.4   3.5
3.6   3.7   3.8   3.9   4.    4.1   4.2   4.3   4.4   4.5   4.6   4.7
4.8   4.9   5.    5.1   5.2   5.3   5.4   5.5   5.6   5.7   5.8   5.9
6.    6.1   6.2   6.3   6.4   6.5   6.6   6.7   6.8   6.9   7.    7.1
7.2   7.3   7.4   7.5   7.6   7.7   7.8   7.9   8.    8.1   8.2   8.3
8.4   8.5   8.6   8.7   8.8   8.9   9.    9.1   9.2   9.3   9.4   9.5
9.6   9.7   9.8   9.9  10. ]
```

Comment: I thought about using it originally, but decided it was conceptually harder because you have to know the number of elements to  space your array out by. But I'm glad you're including it for completeness, +1.

Comment: It depends on what you are using this for. What are you trying to do with the array?

Comment: additionally this may be more semantic for non-python users: `np.linspace(0,1,100,endpoint=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

use [numpy.arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

from the docs:

> numpy.arange([start], stop[, step], dtype=None) Return evenly spaced
>   values within a given interval.

Example:

```
>>> np.arange(3)
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.arange(3.0)
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> np.arange(3,7)
array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.arange(3,7,2)
array([3, 5])
```

for you:

```
 np.arange(0,10,0.1)
```

Comment: would the down-voter care to make a comment?  My answer is valid.

Comment: Well, check the arange docs "When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases."

Comment: Clearly  my answer is valid. The correct results will still be generated. And as I commented on @christians answer I thought this might be conceptually easier than linespace for the OP

Comment: Simply, no. This answer cannot be generalized even a bit. If you generalize it, you might get corrupt results. Also it is not as precise as linspace (though faster). So consider it valid or not, I consider it bad advice.

Comment: Does np.arange() produce a numpy array?

Comment: You can test it by `print type(np.arrange(...))`

Comment: @seberg think why it might not produce consistent results.  It's only in cases where a rounding error created by an odd fraction might give you inconsistent spacing .   For the op s use this works every time,  *is* more efficient,  and is a better introduction into numpy for a user who is taking his first steps.  What more can you ask for from an so answer.  I never asserted that this was the best answer for every possible use case.  The docs were linked so that he could read as much as he wanted about its benefits and limitations